# How to set a specific grid line's color in QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, gridlines

I am working on a Sudoku project, and I used a QTableWidget to create the 9*9 map.

I want to change the fourth row/column grid line's color to yellow (or other highlight colors) to make the 3*3 part highlighted.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The colour of the grid depends of the style.
 You can modify it easily with [QStyleSheet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html):

```
const QString style = "QTableWidget { 
     gridline-color: #fffff8; 
     font-size: 12pt; 
     background-color: red; 
}";
ui->tablet->setStyleSheet(style);
```

See this [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#gridline-color-prop) for more details.

Comment: But I want to highlight the specific grid lines instead of all grid lines.How to set that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`QTableView::columnViewportPosition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html#columnViewportPosition), [`QTableView::rowViewportPosition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html#rowViewportPosition), [`QTableView::rowHeight`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html#rowHeight), and [`QTableView::columnWidth`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html#columnWidth) to get the coordinates of the lines, and draw them in the `painEvent`.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

class TableWidget : public QTableWidget
{
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        QTableView::paintEvent(event);
        if (horizontalHeader()->count() != 9 || verticalHeader()->count() != 9)
            return;

        QPainter painter(viewport());
        //choose the color
        painter.setPen(Qt::white);

        /*
                                           columWidth(8)
                                                ^
                          A           B         |
                          V           V         V
              0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
            0 -------------------------------------
              |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
            1 |-----------------------------------|
              |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
            2 |-----------------------------------|
              |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
       C >  3 |-----------------------------------| <
              |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
            4 |-----------------------------------|
              |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
            5 |-----------------------------------|
              |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
       D >  6 |-----------------------------------| <
              |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
            7 |-----------------------------------|
              |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
            8 |-----------------------------------|
              |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | -> } rowHeight(8)
              -------------------------------------
                          ^           ^

            A: First vertical line
            B: Second vertical line
            C: First horizontal line
            D: Second horizontal line
         */

        //First vertical line
        painter.drawLine(columnViewportPosition(3), 0, columnViewportPosition(3), rowViewportPosition(8) + rowHeight(8) - 1);
        //Second vertical line
        painter.drawLine(columnViewportPosition(6), 0, columnViewportPosition(6), rowViewportPosition(8) + rowHeight(8) - 1);
        //First horizontal line
        painter.drawLine(0, rowViewportPosition(3), columnViewportPosition(8) + columnWidth(8) - 1, rowViewportPosition(3));
        //Second horizontal line
        painter.drawLine(0, rowViewportPosition(6), columnViewportPosition(8) + columnWidth(8) - 1, rowViewportPosition(6));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    TableWidget tableWidget;

    tableWidget.setColumnCount(9);
    tableWidget.setRowCount(9);
    tableWidget.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]